# How to find only id that has different values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns:

| id | num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 7 | 3 |

I want to get as an answer to my query only ids that have more than 1 nums.
For example in my table I would want to get as a result:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |

How should I express my query?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You might need something like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(DISTINCT num) > 1;
```

Google 'Aggregate functions'. Here the aggregate  function is count() and it works always coupled with a GROUP BY clause. Pretty fun.

Comment: GOod suggestions with the aggregate functions. I suggest also using W3Schools for learning SQL. from personal Experience it's really good.